# ToString() for a class property?

Tags: c#

Supposing I have a class "Item", which has three member variables: string name, decimal quantity and string unit. I have got public get/set properties on all three.

Sometimes, I want to display quantity as text along with correct unit, eg. 10m or 100 feet.

My question is, is it possible to have some sort of ToString() function for properties too, so that their text output can be customized?

Thanks,

Saurabh.

Comment: Wow so many solutions! Choosing an answer becomes really difficult, as IMO, many of the solutions suggested seem correct and useful. Two points:
1. There is a UI, for now. However, I still want to do that "formatting" inside the object, because it seems to be so inherent of that object, to return its quantity along with the unit, when not getting involved in some calculations.
2. For now, I am going with Fredrik's solution, as it is providing me with a new ready-to-use property, without the "hassles" of a new object for quantity + unit.

Comment: @virtualmic - It may be the simplest solution but I don't think it's the correct one. You'll have to pay the maintainability tax of mixing concerns at some point.

Comment: Thank you Greg, for you concern. I will definitely try out other approaches too, as you and Anton have suggested. Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you can do is to make a new (readonly) property returning a formatted version:

```
public string QuantityAsString
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Quantity, this.Unit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like your object model isn't correctly factored. What you probably want to do is abstract `Unit` and `Quantity` into another object and then you can override `ToString` for that. This has the advantage of keeping dependent values together, and allowing you to implement things such as conversions between units in the future (e.g. conversion from inchest to feet etc.), e.g.

```
public struct Measure
{
    public Measure(string unit, decimal quantity)
    {
        this.Unit = unit;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public string Unit { get; private set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Quantity, this.Unit);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Measure Measure { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", this.Name, this.Measure);
    }
}
```

Note that I made `Measure` a struct here as it probably has value semantics. If you take this approach you should make it immutable and override Equals/GetHashCode as is appropriate for a struct.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, formatting values to appropriate units is not the responsibility of the `Item` class. Rather, this should be done by some external class.

If, however, you really want to do formatting inside the class, I'd recommend defining a `Unit` class with [implicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx) to convert to `decimal` or `int`s and all the required formatting logic.

Comment: I agree. Formatting is a presentation-layer issue, and shouldn't be encapsulated in the domain-layer entity class.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the object can do sensible things with its units, such as converting between them etc, then it's something that should very much be in the object itself. And who even says there is a UI?

Comment: @Greg Why then would he want to "display quantity as text"?

Comment: @Anton - there are places other than a UI to display things. Trace output, event logs, etc.

Comment: @Greg Then even more so, formatting data for _trace_ output is by no means a responsibility of an object.

Comment: @Anton - It depends. For trace I tend to think an object's ToString is a pretty good representation of itself if it's overridden.

In any case, you're focusing on the wrong part of my comment. Factoring it into a class allows additional features such as conversion between units and adding of measures directly, etc. It's also a good place to put a friendly ToString override. 

As you say, this ToString override may not be suitable for the UI, but it may be a good place to put the logic; take DateTime for example, which has extensive ToString stuff to allow you to get the represenation you want.

Comment: If keeping the formating and order of any object's textual description consistent across UI layers is desired, it's perfectly fine to put the formatting logic in the domain layer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach from the code quality point of view is to create class that will wrap value with unit and provide `.ToString()` there.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the IFormatable interface to have different ToString's

```
public class Item : IFormattable
{
    public string Name;
    public decimal Quantity;
    public string Unit;

    public override string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        switch(format)
        {
            case "quantity": return Quantity + Unit;
            default: return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
Item item = new Item();
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Quantity: {0:quantity}", item);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Have the ToString() of the parent class automatically append these pieces together into a nice format.
2. Wrap the properties in classes and provide a ToString() for those classes

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I implemented the same model. And I made separate classes for Quantity and Unit. It looks like this (it is simplified, in fact there are constructors and overloaded operators):

```
class Quantity
{
    public decimal Value;
    public UnitOfMeasure Unit;

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Value, Unit); 
    }
}

class UnitOfMeasure
{
    public string Name;

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }
}
```